# Proof about meromorphic function which its image is in $ \mathbb{C}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\} $

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ D^{*}=D\left(0,1\right)\setminus\left\{ 0\right\}  $.

Assume $ f:D^{*}\to\mathbb{C}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\}  $ is meromorphic with a sequence of poles $z_n\in D^*$ which converge to $0$.

Prove that the image of $ f $ is densed in $ \mathbb{C}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\}  $.

I'd like to see a good proof for that. I'll share my attempt anyway and I'd be glad to hear what you guys think:

Assume by contradiction that the image of $D^*$ under $ f $ is not densed. Then one can find an open disk $ D\left(a,r\right) $ (center $ a $ and radius $r $), such that $ f\left(D^{*}\right)\cap D\left(a,r\right)=\emptyset $. Thus, the function defined by $ h\left(z\right)=\frac{1}{f\left(z\right)-a} $ is holomorphic in $D^* $ since the denominator never vanish, and  for $z_k$, a pole of $ z$, we have $h(z_k)=0$

Next, notice that $0 $ cannot be a deleted singularity of $ h $ since then by uniqueness theorem we'll get that $ h$ is constant zero, and also $0 $ cannot be a pole of $ h $ because zeroes of meromorphic function cannot accumulate at a pole. Thus we can conclude that $0 $ is an essential singularity of $h $, and thus by the Casorati-Weierstrass theorem, the image of $D^* $ under $h$ is densed in $\mathbb{C} $.

Next, fix $z_0\neq a$ in $D(a,r )$ and fix $\varepsilon>0 $ small enough so that $ D\left(z_{0},\varepsilon\right)\subset D\left(a,r\right) $ and also $a\notin D(z_0,\varepsilon)$.

Then, by the open map theorem, since $ \frac{1}{z-a} $ is holomorphic in an open neighborhood of $D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, we know that $ \left\{ \frac{1}{z-a}:z\in D\left(z_{0},\varepsilon\right)\right\}  $ is an open set, and thus there exists $z_1$ \in $D^*$ such that $ \frac{1}{f\left(z_{1}\right)-a}=h\left(z_{1}\right)\in\left\{ \frac{1}{z-a}:z\in D\left(z_{0},\varepsilon\right)\right\}  $

So we have found $z_1\in D^*$ such that $ f\left(z_{1}\right)\in D\left(z_{0},\varepsilon\right)\subset D\left(a,r\right) $ which is a contradiction.

A few thoughts:

This is not intuitive for me because Im used to be careful of writing things like $f(z)=\infty $ and stuff like that.

1.The proof is correct?

2.Can we say that if $z_k$ is a pole of $ f $ then $f(z_k)=\infty $? can we say that if $z_k $ is a pole of $ f $ then $1/f(z_k)=0$?

3.Im not sure what does it mean that the image is densed in $ f:D^{*}\to\mathbb{C}\cup\left\{ \infty\right\}  $. Proving that the image is densed in $\mathbb{C} $ is enough?

4.I did not talk about the case where $a=\infty$. Does it changes anything?

5.Do you have simpler proof?

Any clarifications would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks fine, but it can be shortened. If $f(D^*)$ omits the disk $D(a,r)$ then $h(z) = 1/(f(z)-a)$ is not only holomorphic in $D^*$ but also *bounded:*
$$
 |h(z)| = \frac{1}{|f(z)-a|} \le \frac 1r \, .
$$
Then Riemann's theorem on removable singularities implies that $h$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. At you correctly pointed out, that is a contradiction to the fact that the zeros of $h$ (which are the poles of $f$) accumulate at $z=0$.

In the case $a = \infty$ there is nothing to show: $f(D^*)$ cannot omit a neighborhood of infinity because it has poles.

Regarding (some of) your other questions: A holomorphic function $f: D\setminus \{ a \} \to \Bbb C$ has a pole at $z=a$ if $\lim_{z \to a} f(z) = \infty$. In that case $f$ is an analytic function from $D$ to the *extended complex plane* (aka Riemann sphere) $\hat{\Bbb C} = \Bbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$, with $f(a) = \infty$. The reciprocal function $1/f$ is meromorphic in $D$ with $(1/f)(a) = 0$.